# Combine two SQL queries, one involving GROUP BY?

Tags: sql

I would like to combine these two SQL queries into one.

```
SELECT COUNT() as total_grants, SUM("CURRENT_AWARD") as total_spent FROM t;
SELECT YEAR, COUNT(), SUM('CURRENT_AWARD') FROM t GROUP BY YEAR AS by_year;
```

The first query shows the total number of grants, and the total spent. The second is the same, but by year.

Is this possible? I've already combined two queries into one in the first query, but I can't figure out how to use an `AS` clause properly in the second query.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: 1 query has 2 columns, the other 3. what do you reckon?

Comment: Can you post sample data and desired output

Answer (score 1):

How about using `CROSS JOIN`

```
SELECT  YEAR, 
        COUNT(*), 
        SUM('CURRENT_AWARD') ,
        t2.total_grants,
        t2.total_spent
FROM    t 
        CROSS JOIN
        (
            SELECT  COUNT(*) as total_grants, 
                    SUM("CURRENT_AWARD") as total_spent 
            FROM    t
        ) t2
GROUP   BY YEAR;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
SELECT BY_YEAR, COUNT(), SUM('CURRENT_AWARD') FROM t GROUP BY rollup(by_year);
```

(I think rollup can be rdbms/version dependent...)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT YEAR, COUNT(*) as total_grants, SUM(CURRENT_AWARD) as total_spent 
FROM t
GROUP BY YEAR;
```

`COUNT(*)` will count all rows in table t, including ones with `NULL`.  If you want to ignore rows with `NULL`, count a specific column.  For example, `COUNT(CURRENT_AWARD)`.

You don't need the quotes around `CURRENT_AWARD` since this identifier contains only letters and underscores.